# Conversion numeric to long C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database field called "PIECE" which datatype is NUMERIC(11,0), 
I must  convert this field to a long-datatype.
This without any luck or succes, I'll keep getting the same error:
Wrong conversion...

I tried the next things:

```
(long)PIECE
long.Parse(PIECE.ToString().Trim())
```

But I'm still having the wrong conversion message, 
is here someone who can help me?

Comment: "Wrong conversion..." is not a .NET exception. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Include all relevant details: amongst others, the code you use to query the database and preferably some example input.

Comment: Do you have the full error message and the `PIECE` value which is generating that error?

Comment: use decimal instead of long and then check.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
var result = Convert.ToInt64(PIECE);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zahhahw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This will do _what_? If `long.Parse` doesn't work, so won't this.